# How Amazon S3 provides unlimited storage space?

Tags: storage, capacity-planning

In order to maintain user uploaded images in website becomes very tough as the number of images are increasing. In the long run the available disk space will come to 0 bytes.

Amazon generally provides unlimited space for their S3 service. If we want to provide unlimited space to our website what are the possible ways?

Comment: Use Amazon S3? There's not really a viable answer here other than use a service that can provide this, or keep buying more disks.

Comment: I don't understand your tags. You've really cast a wide net here.

Answer (score 7):

> becomes very tough as the number of images are increasing

If you are doing things right, it usually should become much easier as you have a larger volume.  If a increase in usage as making things exponentially worse, then you probably have something designed incorrectly.

> How Amazon S3 provides unlimited storage space?

For someone as large as Amazon, or Google, I can guess there is a fixed cost for all the R&D, and the core infrastructure for a huge storage.  Or to put it differently, after the first few hundred TB, adding more probably becomes cheaper.

Most huge scaling problems tend to have a logarithmic growth.  Lets put it this way, say you have a service running on a single server and you have reach the capacity of that server.  Adjusting the application and setting up the infrastructure so your system can span two servers takes a huge investment.  On the other hand, lets say you have a service running on a cluster of 100 servers, adding the 101st server is likely extremely easy to do.  By that point you have solved all the growth problems, and you know what how to add another server, and probably even have it almost completely automated.

[image: Log Growth]

To summarize, Amazon provides a nearly unlimited amount of storage by being so huge that adding storage is easy for them, they have already worked everything out.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly! this is how it's done, you need to figure out a method so that expansion costs you the least possible, so that the return on investment can make sense.
The selling point is that they can provide you the customer a service that you *can* do yourself, but once you look at the cost for 1, 2, even 10 servers, your product/service that you wish to provide doesn't really give you a great return because of the expense.

So long as cloud providers can provide you the same service for 1 - 100/0/0 servers cheaper than you can yourself, they stay in business. Brilliant hey?

In fact, some business models can only really work if they are massive. (can you imagine T-Mobile with just 50,000 customers?)

We just have to wait for economies of scale to tip in our favour, but even when they do, they also tip in cloud providers favour too - So I reckon they are here to stay.

Oh, and to answer your question

> Amazon generally provides unlimited
>   space for their S3 service. If we want
>   to provide unlimited space to our
>   website what are the possible ways?

The answer would be to use Amazons services - Oh, and these days I like to think that unlimited means "More than you can use" not, "There will always be more for me" If that makes sense.